# What is probability of event A ? Please check whether my answer is correct?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> The probability of an event $B$ is $P_1$. The probability that events
>   $A$ and $B$ occur together is $P_2$ while the probability that $A$ and
>   $B'$ occur together is $P_3$. The probability of the event $A$ in
>   terms of $P_1,P_2\; \text{and}\; P_3$ is_________.

---

My explanation is $:$

---

Given ,

probability of event $B$ (i.e., $P(B)$) = $P_1$  ,

probability that events $A$ and $B$ occur together(i.e.,$P(A$ &$ B)$) = $P_2$ ,

probability that events $A$ and $B'$ occur together(i.e.,$P(A$ &$ B')$) = $P_3$ .

using inclusion-exclusion rule ,

$P(A$ &$ B') = P(A) - P(A $&$ B)$

so,

$P_3 = P(A) - P_2$

therefore ,

$P(A) = P_2 + P_3$

---

> *Please check whether my answer is correct ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct.